# Convert string to sentence case but leave acronyms untouched

Tags: string

This is not a language-specific question.

I have a string in ALL CAPS. This string comes in from a separate source and for some reason is always in all caps.

I've been given the task of making the string a little more reader-friendly so I decided to just slap a sentence case converter method on it using simple regex.

The thing is, there are a lot of acronyms used in this string and I would like to keep them unaffected. Things like country codes(US, CA, JP, FR, etc...), or airport codes(LAX, LGA) and sometimes many others.

Now I'm guessing I would first need a list of the acronyms in a database or something, of all the possible airport codes, country codes and a list of commonly used acronyms like ETA, COD, etc...

Once I have this database created, how can I apply it to the string in question?? How can I prevent the word "us" being changed to US and vice-versa?? What I basically wanna know is, how do I take what's in the DB and apply all the necessary changes to the string?

Remember, I get the original string in ALL CAPS so there's no way to differentiate.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's not really possible. You would need semantic analysis to differentiate between "us" and "US".

Comment: Right, but for the obvious ones like LGA? What would the standard procedure be to process my string correctly??

Comment: This problem is called [truecasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truecasing). It's non-trivial and usually solved using statistical language models.

Comment: Thanks larsmans. I wasn't aware of the term used for this kind of conversion. Unfortunately I tried Googling the term and nothing comes up about how to apply this to a computer program.

Answer (score 1):

Something close to this can be done with [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html), which provides the [titleize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize) method (which does the work for [String.titleize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-titleize)).

First, define your own [inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) in an initializer.

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'US'
end
```

Restart your app to pick up the change. Now `titleize` knows how to handle "US". Fire up a Rails console to check it out:

```
> "us".titleize
=> "US"
```

Next, check out the source code for `titleize`. Once you understand it, reopen the Inflector class in an initializer and define your own method that doesn't capitalize the first letter of each word. Call it something nifty, like `decapitalize`.

```
module ActiveSupport::Inflector
  def decapitalize(word)
    humanize(underscore(word)) # you may enhance this a bit
  end
end

class String
  def decapitalize
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.decapitalize(self)
  end
end
```

#### Caveats and Limitations

You may need to tweak the code, but I think it's close.

Here are some sentences this solution won't handle very well:

```
> "US STATES VISITED BY US".titleize
=> "US States Visited By US"
> "COLUMBIA (CO) EXPORTS ARE PROCESSED BY ACME BUILDING CO.".decapitalize
=> "Columbia (CO) exports are processed by acme building CO."
```